# Django - Permission Error when opening pipe to write

Tags: python, django, permissions, uwsgi, named-pipes

I have problem with my Django application which communicates with my daemon my named pipe:

> Django application -> garage_gate_pipe -> python daemon

The daemon is used by `gate` user, and I assumed that `www-data` is responsible for running my Django app (application is driven by `uwsgi`), so I've added `www-data` to `gate` group:

```
$ sudo -u www-data groups
gate www-data
```

and I've granted proper access rights for `garage_gate_pipe`:

```
prw-rw---- 1 gate gate 0 Jul  2 17:55 garage_gate_pipe
```

unfortunately it didn't work because of permission error:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/path/to/garage_gate_pipe'

Here's the error line:

```
pipeout = open(settings.PIPE_NAME, 'w')
```

It's very strange, because in commandline everything worked fine:

```
echo -n 'Open' | sudo -u www-data tee ./garage_gate_pipe
```

I decided to check which user is responsible for managing Django app, so I've changed permissions of pipe:

```
sudo chmod 666 garage_gate_pipe
```

and decided to invoke `whoami` command from shell and send it to my named pipe and print it in my python daemon:

```
os.system("whoami > /home/gate/garage_gate/gate_gpio/garage_gate_pipe")
pipeout = open(settings.PIPE_NAME, 'w')
```

And everything worked...

The output from my daemon was:

> 'www-data
>
> '

It's strange, because my uwsgi Django app seems to be ran by `www-data` user.

My named pipe `garage_gate_pipe` has good access rights, so I can write to it from commandline, but from django application it doesn't work unless I add write permission for `others`...

Any idea what can I change to make this solution working with `660` permissions for `garage_gate_pipe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `--gid` parameter in uwsgi command in my `/etc/rc.local` script, which is responsible for starting server on start:

```
/usr/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid gate
```

Now it works.